# Change font type in tikztimingtable without displacing signals

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, tikz-timing, timing-diagrams

I decided to play a little bit with the tikztimingtable, however I'm not sure that I "like" the font used in the signal labels

[image]

So I tried to change it by adding a `[font=\rmfamily]` in front of the first label. However this resulted in the signals getting displaced (see image below)

[image]

As you can see the signals no longer reaches the t_10. The code is down below. Is it possible to change the font to the roman family?

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}
        handshake\_out\_RPi     & [thin] 3L 6H 6L 9H 6L\\
        data\_out\_RPi          & [thin] 3Z[black] 6D 6Z[black] 9D 6Z[black]\\
        handshake\_out\_UR5         & [thin] 6L 6H 9L 6H 3L\\
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\vertlines[help lines, dotted]{0,3,...,30}
\foreach \i [count=\col from 0] in {0,3,...,30}
    \node[font=\scriptsize] at (\i,3) {$t_{\col}$};
\end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikztimingtable}%
```

And with the roman family font:

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}
[font = \rmfamily]      handshake\_out\_RPi     & [thin] 3L 6H 6L 9H 6L\\
                        data\_out\_RPi          & [thin] 3Z[black] 6D 6Z[black] 9D 6Z[black]\\
                        handshake\_out\_UR5         & [thin] 6L 6H 9L 6H 3L\\
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\vertlines[help lines, dotted]{0,3,...,30}
\foreach \i [count=\col from 0] in {0,3,...,30}
    \node[font=\scriptsize] at (\i,3) {$t_{\col}$};
\end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikztimingtable}%
```

Comment: I guess that the changing font affects also the spacing. Try to change only for the label `\textrm{handshake\_out\_RPi}`.

Comment: Sigur, thank you. That works. Do you know how i can add some spacing between the signals, and increase the signal's height?

Comment: Since I don't know how the signal was drawn it is difficulty to say. But try to scale only the `y` coordinates. Use `\begin{tikztimingtable}[yscale=1.1]` for example to increase 10%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sigur suggested, this is the answer for my question:

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}[yscale=1.5]
        \texttt{Handshake out RPi}      & [thin] 4L 8H 8L 12H 8L\\
        \texttt{Data out RPi}           & [thin] 4Z[black] 8D 8Z[black] 12D 8Z[black]\\
        \texttt{Handshake out UR5}      & [thin] 8L 8H 12L 8H 4L\\
        %\textsf{•}
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\vertlines[help lines, dotted]{0,4,...,40}
\foreach \i [count=\col from 0] in {0,4,...,40}
    \node[font=\scriptsize] at (\i,2) {$t_{\col}$};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}%
```

Where the yscale option increases the heights of the signals. So it now looks beautiful:

[image]